# i have problem to make rss reader (is use RecyclerView and Gson and CardView)

Tags: android

i have problem
i want to show rss my web
i use RecyclerView and CardView and Gson 
on my phone have not error but in my emolator has error
when i click on one cardView 
tnx
i have problem
i want to show rss my web
i use RecyclerView and CardView and Gson 
on my phone have not error but in my emolator has error
when i click on one cardView 
tnx
i have problem
i want to show rss my web
i use RecyclerView and CardView and Gson 
on my phone have not error but in my emolator has error
when i click on one cardView 
tnx
i have problem
i want to show rss my web
i use RecyclerView and CardView and Gson 
on my phone have not error but in my emolator has error
when i click on one cardView 
tnx

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
        at com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.Adapter.FeedAdapter$1.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:74)
        at com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.Adapter.FeedViewHolder.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:37)
```

package com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.Adapter;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.Mudel.RSSObject;
import com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.R;
import com.holdingabdolbaghi.co.interfac.ItemClickListener;

class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener , View.OnLongClickListener{
    public TextView txtTitle , txtPubData , txtContent;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        txtContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtPubData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtpubData);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view , getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view , getAdapterPosition(),true);
        return true;
    }
}
public class FeedAdapter  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder>{
    private RSSObject rssObject;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FeedAdapter (RSSObject rssObject , Context mContext){
        this.rssObject = rssObject;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtPubData.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean islongClick) {
                if(!islongClick){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rssObject.items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: ­­­­­­­-­­­­­­­­1­­­­­­­ You provide no context or info, so there is no way we can try to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all already: If you start an `Activity` from a context other than an `Activity` context (say, `Application`, `Service` or any other context), Android requires you to explicitely give it the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, because Android needs to create a new task for that new activity as it otherwise doesn't know to which existing task it should add your new activity to.

If you'd start your `Activity` from an existing `Activity`, the new one could use the same "affinity", i.e. the same task as the old one, hence wouldn't lead to a duplicate entry in the Android app switcher.

Since you're in-app, I suspect you use the `Application` context and not some view context to start the new `Activity`. If you request the context of a view (via `View.getContext()`) you usually get the context of the `Activity` returned in whose view tree your view sits in.

Comment: i do not understand

Comment: `FeedAdapter (RSSObject rssObject , Context mContext)` - where is this constructor called? Do you use `Application` as second argument eventually? This would be the issue! You need to use `this` if you are inside an `Activity` or `requireActivity()` if you're doing this inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: i use this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APInjVO0WkQ